# Looking for R-compatible geospatial datasets

Tags: data, r

I try to work with geospatial data of North America.
Is there any high-resolution map material available for/in R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The R package rgdal has functions for reading in data that can be read by the GDAL (for raster) and OGR (for vector) libraries. This includes Shapefiles, GeoTiff, GML, Arc/Info Grid, GPX, GeoJSON etc etc etc etc. I could go on.

If you can't find the data you want in one of the formats that R can read via the rgdal package, then I would be very surprised. You don't need special map data for R, you can use almost anything.

Read the R Spatial Task View for everything you need to know about spatial data in R.

http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Spatial.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at
maps ( http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/maps/index.html )
and 
mapdata ( http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mapdata/index.html )
for higher resolutions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer! Are there any higher resolutions and more recent maps also available?

Comment: You can use the GADM data http://www.gadm.org/ in R.  You can download vector data directly in R format.